# "to the fullest"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I got a requirement which says :

> The number comprises to the fullest 20 characters.

Does it mean the number **can be** as long as 20 characters or that the number **must** be 20 characters long?

Comment: I agree the question isn't useful as its really specific and based on a grammatical error. But I couldn't know beforehand therefore my request here.
And for posterity unless the thread is removed, the writer meant "at maximum 20 characters".
I also think it's important to have an answer as I received with proper use of the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make sense.

If I had to decide what was meant I would guess "X comprises, at most, 20 characters". Either that or that X should be written using the 20 widest characters, but this seems ridiculous.

The reason the sentence does not work is that "to the fullest" is used to say that the minimum action to be taken will be or should be the maximum action. It is rhetoric used to emphasise the importance of something.

There are two set phrases that exemplify this:

> You will be prosecuted to the fullest extent of the law.

This means that your transgression will garner the worst punishment the law allows. This emphasises the severity of the transgression.

> Live your life to the fullest.

This means that, at a minimum, you should be doing the most you can with your life. Because life is precious and I want to emphasise that.

So, with this in mind, if I were to try and interpret your sentence

> The number comprises to the fullest 20 characters

I suppose I would have to say that at a minimum, the number will contain 20 characters, and that is the maximum. Also, that there is some importance about the 20 characters. Perhaps they are more important that any other characters.

Because your sentence is not rhetorical, using "to the fullest" does not make sense.

Given this, you should ask the person who gave you the requirement to clarify what they want.

Comment: Yes I agree the question has been asked since the sentence is not correct and we just can suppose what he/she meant. And thanks for the detailed information.

Comment: I don't think our supposing is going to be helpful, you should really ask the person who gave you the requirement what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

That sentence is not grammatical — its writer must not be a native English speaker — but I'm reasonably confident that by "to the fullest" (s)he meant "at most". If so, then it means your first suggestion: the number may be twenty characters long, or may be shorter than that.

Comment: You're pretty right, the writer is not a native English speaker. I agree with your analyze. I was unsure because of "fullest" which I see as something completely full.

Comment: How is this going to help other users? 'I'm reasonably confident ...' and '[t]hat sentence is not grammatical' show that the question and answer here are unsuitable for ELU. If you wish to help OP, this should be given as a comment; if you wish to maintain standards on ELU, the question should be close-voted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The OP had no way of knowing that this usage was idiosyncratic, and therefore that the question about it was more localized than we'd like. If the only way to determine that a question is inappropriate is to ask it and see what the answer is, then I don't think the question is really inappropriate.

Comment: OP should have included a link to the original (or more context), to show the general standard of grammar used, and a comment about how frequently "comprises to the fullest" occurs on the internet according to Google. ELU is aimed at linguists. Many inappropriate questions are posted here; close-voting is available to remove unsuitable questions. Your comment is essentially saying that all questions should be allowed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't see how "comprises to the fullest" is relevant. The OP's example is using the standard phrase "to the fullest"; it's using it in a nonstandard way, but how was the OP to know that? I'm not saying that all questions should be allowed, I'm saying that whether a *question* is allowed should not depend on what the right *answer* is.

Comment: The first dictionary I looked in defined the set phrase 'to the fullest' as 'as much as possible' (Macmillan) and not 'at most'. Even if this didn't fully answer OP's question, a dictionary definition should have been given.  The question is off-topic as lacking any reasonable reference. Your answer is also lacking any support from an accepted authority.